# Query for dates which are not present in a table

Tags: sql, database, oracle

Consider a table ABC which has a column of date type.
How can we get all the dates of a range (between start date and end date) which are not present in the table.
This can be done in PLSQL.I am searching a SQL query for it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to generate the arbitrary list of dates that you want to check for:

http://hashfactor.wordpress.com/2009/04/08/sql-generating-series-of-numbers-in-oracle/

e.g.:

```
-- generate 1..20
SELECT ROWNUM N FROM dual
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 20
```

Then left join with your table, or use a where not exists subquery (which will likely be faster) to fetch the dates amongst those you've generated that contains no matching record.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your table's dates do not include a time element (ie. they are effectively recorded as at midnight), try:

```
select check_date
from (select :start_date + level - 1 check_date
      from dual
      connect by level <= 1 + :end_date - :start_date) d
where not exists
(select null from mytable where mydate = check_date)
```

Answer (score 0):

Given a date column in order to do this you need to generate a list of all possible dates between the start and end date and then remove those dates that already exist. As [Mark has already suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16999287/458741) the obvious way to generate the list of all dates is to use a hierarchical query. You can also do this without knowing the dates in advance though.

```
with the_dates as (
  select date_col 
    from my_table 
         )
 , date_range as (
  select max(date_col) as maxdate, min(date_col) as mindate 
    from the_dates 
         )
 select mindate + level
   from date_range
connect by level <= maxdate - mindate
  minus
 select date_col
   from the_dates
        ;
```

[Here's a SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/56c7c/2)

The point of the second layer of the CTE is to have a "table" that has all the information you need but is only one row so that the hierarchical query will work correctly.